# Adding pagination to my custom blog page using a foreach post loop

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I built a custom blog page in my custom wordpress theme, and I'm trying to add pagination to the blog page. Im' using a foreach loop, instead your standard "if while post" loop.

Everything is working find, however I'm not sure where to add "paged" as an argument.

Here is my code:

```
<?php if (is_page( 'Blog' )) : ?>

                                <?php
                                    //Get the Posts
                                    $posts = get_posts();
                                    foreach ($posts as $post) :
                                    setup_postdata( $post );

                                    //Setup Post data
                                    $haystack = get_the_category($post->ID);
                                    $i = count($haystack);
                                    $string = "";

                                    for ($j=0; $j < $i; $j++) {
                                        $string .= " ";
                                        $string .= $haystack[$j]->slug;
                                    }

                                    $link = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'large', false );

                                    $href = get_the_permalink();

                                    $theCat = wp_get_post_categories($post->ID);

                                    if (has_post_thumbnail($post->ID)){
                                        $theCols = 'span12'; 
                                        $imgWidth = 'span4';
                                        $contentWidth = 'span8';
                                    } else {
                                        $theCols = 'span12'; 
                                        $imgContainer ='display: none;';
                                        $contentWidth = 'width: 100%;';
                                    } 
                                ?>

                                <div class="<?php echo $string;?>">
                                    <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="post-content <?php echo $theCols;?> group nopad">
                                        <div class="post-content--image <?php echo $imgWidth;?> <?php echo $imgContainer;?>">
                                            <img src="<?php echo $link[0]; ?>">
                                        </div>

                                        <!-- Post Content -->
                                        <div class="post-content--container <?php echo $contentWidth;?>">
                                            <?php
                                                $post_title = get_the_title();
                                                $post_title = explode(' ', $post_title);
                                                $title = '';

                                                for ($i=0; $i < 5 ; $i++) {
                                                    $title .= $post_title[$i];
                                                    $title .= ($i == 50) ? "..." : " ";
                                                }
                                            ?>

                                            <p class="post-content--date"><?php echo get_the_date('d M Y'); ?></p>

                                            <h4 class="post-content--heading"><?php echo $title;?></h4>

                                            <p class="post-content--cat"><?php echo $string;?></p>

                                            <div class="post-content--text">
                                                <?php
                                                    if ($theCat){ 
                                                        $str = substr(get_the_excerpt(), 0,255); 
                                                    } else {
                                                        $str = get_the_excerpt();
                                                    }

                                                    $n = strpos($str, '<a');

                                                    if ($n > 0){
                                                        $rest = substr($str, 0, $n);
                                                        echo $rest;
                                                    } else {
                                                        echo $str;
                                                    }
                                                ?> ...
                                            </div>

                                            <a href="<?php echo $href;?>"><button class="see-more-btn">Read More</button></a>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            <?php endforeach;
                                wp_reset_postdata();?>

                            <?php else : ?>

                                    <p>Critiria Not Found</p>

                            <?php endif; ?>
```

what am I missing? Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to use the `get_posts` function you need to set the `posts_per_page` and `offset` parameters. You need to check the current page and set the offset according to how many posts you are showing per page and the current page. For eg. On Page 2 and showing 5 posts per page you need to set the offset to 5 in order to skip the first 5 posts.

**Note: The posts_per_page parameter does NOT work without setting the offset parameter.**

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => 5,
    'offset'           => 0
);
$posts_array = get_posts( $args );
```

One other way is to use the `WP_Query` and instead of passing the offset argument you just pass the page argument only like the example below where `get_query_var('paged')` get the value of the ?paged=x and if it its not set will default to '1'.

```
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'paged' => $paged ) );
```

If you are going to use `WP_Query` you need to change from `foreach` to:

```
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();

        $post_id = get_the_ID();
        $haystack = get_the_category($post_id);
        $i = count($haystack);
    }
}
```

To output the pagination links after the WP_Query you can use the `paginate_links` function as below. The advantage of using WP_Query is that you will also get the total number of posts found matching the current query parameters in `found_posts` and other values which you might need like `max_num_pages`.

```
echo paginate_links( array(
    'base'         => '%_%',
    'total'        => $query->max_num_pages,
    'current'      => max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) ),
    'format'       => '?paged=%#%',
    'show_all'     => false,
    'prev_next'    => true,
    'prev_text'    => __('« Previous'),,
    'next_text'    => __('Next »'),
    'add_args'     => false,
    'add_fragment' => '',
) );
```

get_posts: https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

WP_Query: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters
paginate_links: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links